# Reporting services expression #Error with "mid"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a problem with a expression in a reporting services 2012. The expression is:

```
iif(IsNothing(Fields!CHEGADA_LUME.Value)," ",mid(Fields!CHEGADA_LUME.Value,12,instr(Fields!CHEGADA_LUME.Value,":00")-12))
```

When, the value is null (first condition is true), the expression returns "#Error". However, if the value is not null, the expression works good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iif evaluates both expressions not matter which one returns.

Mid cannot accept null as value (it expects integer), so you have to return 0 as the third parameter of mid when your string is null, making an extra check.

```
=iif(
IsNothing(Fields!CHEGADA_LUME.Value),
" ",
mid(Fields!CHEGADA_LUME.Value,12,iif(
IsNothing(Fields!CHEGADA_LUME.Value),0,instr(Fields!CHEGADA_LUME.Value,":00")-12)
))
```